# Establishing connection in windows Phone with the server

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-7

Am a ASP.Net Web App Developer. and am new to Windows Phone Developement. 
I want a help regarding how to place a request to server windows phone and how to receive the response back. 
Consider, my local lost is my server and App is running in windows Emulator.
Any kind of sample code for Both phone and the server side will be greatly appreciated.
Iam madly in search this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to do the following:

1. Create a simple database in sql server to store data
2. Add a ASP.NET web project to our solution
3. Create an entity data model for your newly created table
4. Create and configure a WCF Data Service to expose the table as an OData endpoint
5. Build the web site
6. From the Phone project, Add a service reference to the service we created in step 3
7. Configure the phone application to use the data service for retrieving, updating and inserting task data.

I have a blog post going over each of these steps here:

http://www.ritzcovan.com/2012/02/building-a-simple-windows-phone-apppart-4/

That should get you going in the right direction